# google maps v3 events in qooxdoo mobile

Tags: google-maps, mobile, google-maps-api-3, qooxdoo

I have a qooxdoo mobile app where I am trying to implement a google map. I have looked at the openlayers example,but it does not suit my needs. The issue I have is that the events attached to google map do not get triggered or at least do not reach the handlers i defined. Stand alone, outside qooxdoo mobile, it works fine. I've trigered the loadMapLibrary directly from inte _initialize function and as a listener on the appear event of the page. Both times the map gets displayed fine, but no events are handled.

I understand I can trigger qx events on the div, but they lack the google.maps properties i need, like lat/lon etc. What am I doing wrong.

The example at http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/demobrowser/#showcase~Maps.html for desktop seems to operate in the way i implemented it. Am I missing something?

```
_loadMapLibrary: function() {

        var self = this;
        var req = new qx.bom.request.Script();

        req.onload = function() {
            self._G = google.maps;
            self._createMap();
        }

        req.open("GET", self._mapUri);
        req.send();
    },

    _createMap: function() {
        var mapContainer = document.getElementById("googleMap");

        var chicago = new this._G.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            mapTypeId: this._G.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: chicago
        //        draggable: false,
        //        panControl: false

        }
        this._map = new this._G.Map(mapContainer, myOptions);

        google.maps.event.addListener(this._map, 'click', this._startDrawing);
        google.maps.event.addListener(this._map, 'mousemove', this._mapMouseMove);
    //      document.addEventListener("touchmove",function(e) {
    //        //log('touchmove');
    //        e.preventDefault();
    //      });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I had already loaded the google maps api for geocoding elsewhere in the app.

removed the  var req = new qx.bom.request.Script(); etc. just plain use the api, and all works OK.